# Mobile Video in HTML5 - Close video player or redirect after completion

Tags: jquery, html, video, redirect, mobile

I have nearly completed a mobile Web site which leverages the jquery mobile framework but have run into a few problems regarding the videos I am serving.  Both iPhone and Android open a video in their respective device’s native player.  Once the video ends the screen goes black.  I would like, however, the player to close and then make the browser page they selected the video from visible again.  Is there a way to simply close the player dynamically once the video has completed?  I have looked at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741493/how-do-you-detect-html5-video-events) as well as this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208561/redirecting-the-page-after-a-video-plays-using-an-html5-video-player) but there does not seem to be a clear answer.  My test site is [here](http://www.magarottos.com/Staging/ITW/#TNLD5).

Is it easier to close the iPhone/Android video player or do a redirect back to page?  Or is this really the same action but simply stated differently?

Answer (score 1):

when using Android, the video closed automatically for me without any extra code.

I used the following code for iOS to close the video player (using jquery to bind event):

```
    if(isiPhone){
        $('#video_element').bind('ended', function(){
            document.getElementById('video_element').webkitExitFullScreen();
        });
    }
```

Check out the following url for details:
http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Reference/HTMLVideoElementClassReference/HTMLVideoElement/HTMLVideoElement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009356